# React CSS Transition Group on Custom Components

Tags: reactjs, components, transition

I'm getting an `Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...)` error while trying to add `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to my collection of components.

My parent render function looks like:

```
var notes = this.props.notes.reverse().map(function (v) {
      return <NoteItem note={v} key={v.id} />;
    });

    return (
      <div className="note-container">
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" >
          {notes}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
```

And the `Note` component's render function returns:

```
return (
      <div>
        <div className={classNames} onClick={this._onClick}>
          {note.text}
        </div>
        { showDetails ? <NoteItemDetails note={note} /> : null }
      </div>
    );
```

`NoteItemDetails` component might be unrelevant there.

Full error message is:

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's 'render' method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.`

Any solutions, which might help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was using `require('react/tools')` while the modules use `require('React')` and React was loaded two times by browserify.

Letter case matters!